# Select Distinct and Count in Grid View

Tags: asp.net

I need some help....

this is the example of my database table:

```
Record_ID    User_ID    Record
-------------------------------
001          A111111    file1
002          A111111    fileq
003          A222222    file2
004          A222222    file3
005          A111111    file4
006          A333333    file5
007          A333333    file6
```

I want it to show up in Grid view like below:

```
User_ID    Total_Record
-----------------------
A111111         3
A222222         2
A333333         2
```

> SELECT count(*) as total_record FROM Table where user_id

I know the sql syntax but I don't know how to create the grid view for show result this query 
please help me

Comment: What SQL type are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is a little off, you are going to need a GROUP BY User_ID.  I've included code for a SqlDataSource and GridView below, with modified SQL.  Of course, you'll also need to set the ConnectionString for the data source.

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="dsMySource"
        SelectCommand="SELECT user_id, count(*) as total_record FROM myTable GROUP BY User_ID">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvCount" DataSourceID="dsMySource" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="User_ID" DataField="User_ID" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="total_record " DataField="total_record" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```